# How to override event handler function of child component from parent component in react.js

Tags: event-handling, reactjs

```
/** @jsx React.DOM */

var Button = React.createClass({
  handleClick: function(){
    console.log(' FROM BUTTON')
  },
  render: function() {
    return <input type='button' onClick={this.handleClick} value={this.props.dname}/>;
  } 
});

var Text = React.createClass({
  render: function() {
    return <input type='text' onClick={this.handleClick} value={this.props.ival}/>;
  } 
});


var search = React.createClass({
  handleClick: function() {
    console.log('searching')
  },
  render: function(){
    return (
      <div>
        <Text/>
        <Button dname={this.props.dname} onClick={this.handleClick} />
      </div>
    );
  }
});

React.renderComponent(<search dname='Look up' fname='Search'/> , document.body);
```

I have created a button and text component and included them in a search component now i want to override the default handleClick event of button with search component's handler.
But this.handleClick is pointing to button component's event handler.. please help..
i need  FROM SEARCH on click instead i got FROM BUTTON..

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are 99% percent there.

React uses a [one-way data-flow](http://facebook.github.io/react/docs/thinking-in-react.html#step-2-build-a-static-version-in-react).  So, events on nested components will not propagate to their parents.

**You must propagate events manually**

Change your `<Button>`s `handleClick` function to call the `this.props.handleClick` function passed in from it's `<Search>` parent:

```
var Button = React.createClass({
  handleClick: function () {
    this.props.onClick();
  },

  ...

});
```

Attached is a fiddle of your original post, with the required change.  Instead of logging `FROM BUTTON`, it will now alert `searching`.

http://jsfiddle.net/chantastic/VwfTc/1/

Answer (score 1):

You need to change your `Button` component to allow such behaviour:

```
var Button = React.createClass({
  handleClick: function(){
    console.log(' FROM BUTTON')
  },
  render: function() {
    return (
      <input type='button'
        onClick={this.props.onClick || this.handleClick}
        value={this.props.dname} />
    );
  }   
});
```

note the `onClick={this.props.onClick || this.handleClick}`.

That way if you pass an `onClick` prop when instantiating `Button` it will have a preference over the `Button`'s `handleClick` method.

Comment: The method `getDefaultProps` is used to set default properties and automatically gets the overriding behaviour when a prop is sent in.

Answer (score 0):

Or if you can execute both of them, you can put

```
class Button extends React.Component {


handleClick = () => {
console.log("from buttom");

if (this.props.hasOwnProperty('onClick')){
   this.props.onClick();
}
```

};

You would check whether the object has the specified property and run it