# Why does React warn me against binding a component method to the object?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have this here component. I want to pass down a call handler to each listElement I create. If I do it like below, with `bind(this)`, it works properly. The problem is that I get this warning from React in the console: `bind(): You are binding a component method to the component. React does this for you automatically in a high-performance way, so you can safely remove this call.`

```
var MyList = React.createClass({
  render: function () {
    var listElements = this.props.myListValues.map(function (val) {
      return (
        <ListElement onCallHandler={this.props.parentsCallHandler} val={val} />
        );
    }.bind(this));
    return (
      <ul>
          {listElements}
      </ul>
      );
  }
});
```

If I don't bind it, my children don't know about the call handler. What could I have done differently?

PS:

I know about destructuring assignments, like explained http://facebook.github.io/react/docs/transferring-props.html#transferring-with-...-in-jsx, but I don't want to use Harmony.

Comment: By "call handler" do you mean event handler? Events should bubble up to the parent and can be captured there. What am I missing?

Comment: I'm not seeing that error: http://jsfiddle.net/s6dok0xv.

Answer (score 31, accepted):

The error is coming from somewhere else in the code.  You get the error when you do `this.someFunction.bind(something)` and something isn't `null`.

```
this.someFunction.bind({}, foo);    // warning
this.someFunction.bind(this, foo);  // warning, you're doing this
this.someFunction.bind(null, foo);  // okay!
```

Do a search for `.bind(this` in your code to find the offending line.

Comment: Oh, you're right, it was somewhere else. I'm embarrassed now

Comment: @FakeRainBrigand It seems that it now doesn't warn in the second case, `.bind(this, foo)`. It does with `.bind(this)`. Tested with react@0.13.1. https://jsfiddle.net/69z2wepo/17453/ And the docs currently show doing just that: https://facebook.github.io/react/tips/communicate-between-components.html. This story of when to bind and when not to in React seems perhaps overly complicated.

Comment: The reason why `.bind(null,` works is that, since react autobinds since [v0.4](http://facebook.github.io/react/blog/2013/07/02/react-v0-4-autobind-by-default.html), by doing `.bind(null`, we are essentiall execute `this.methond.bind(this).bind(null, arg1, arg2)`. Just thought some of you may want to know **why** it worked.

Answer (score 4):

Here is updated docs example

```
React.createClass({
  onClick: function(event) {/* do something with this */},
  render: function() {
    return <button onClick={this.onClick} />;
  }
});
```

[Update in ReactJS Docs](http://facebook.github.io/react/blog/2013/07/02/react-v0-4-autobind-by-default.html)