# bind() in render method gives me a warning?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

My code is working properly but it gives me a warning

Warning: bind(): You are binding a component method to the component. React does this for you automatically in a high-performance way, so you can safely remove this call.

I also use onClick={this.myFun.bind(null,"myvalue")} as describe in the [Why does React warn me against binding a component method to the object?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26786786/why-does-react-warn-me-against-binding-a-component-method-to-the-object)

Still it give me warning.

My Code :

```
var MyClass = React.createClass({
  myFun : function (value){  
      console.log(value);  
  },
  render: function () {
  var that = this; 
    var card = this.props.data.map(function (val,key) {
      return (
        <p onClick={that.myFun.bind(null,val)}> Click Me</p>
        );
    });
    return (  
        <div>
        {card}  
        </div>
      );
  }
});
```

Comment: why are you doing that? React clearly say it clear

Comment: I am not passing this to bind function.

Comment: are you sure this is working: `var this = that`?

Comment: @Muhaimin sorry this is var that =this ;

Comment: You are getting this warning because `myFun` is already bound. You could do `<p onClick={function() { that.myFun(val); }}>` instead.

Comment: @FelixKling This is also not working for me.

Answer (score 1):

There are a few things wrong with your code

1. `render: function () {
   var this = that;`

   should be

   `render: function () {
   var that = this;`
2. `return ( {card})` will give an error that `you may have returned undefined or null or an Object` and hence you need to wrap it inside a div like `<div>{card}</div>` to return a React Element.
3. You component name must begin with a upper case Character. See the explanation here: [React - Adding component after AJAX to view](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41216654/react-adding-component-after-ajax-to-view/41216726#41216726)

See the working demo

```js
var MyClass = React.createClass({
  myFun : function (value){  
      console.log(value);  
  },
  render: function () {
    var that = this;
    var card = this.props.data.map(function (val,key) {
      return (
        <p key={key} onClick={that.myFun.bind(null,val)}> Click Me</p>
        );
    });
    return (
        <div>{card}</div>
      );
  }
}); 

ReactDOM.render(<MyClass data={['1', '2']}/>, document.getElementById('app'))
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react-dom.js"></script>
<div id="app"></div>
```

> NOTE: `React.createClass` is deprecated and will be removed in v16.0
>   and hence you should write your component by extending
>   `React.Component` syntax

Comment: *"will give an error because card may be undefined or null "* No it won't. It's actually object shorthand notation and will be the same as `{card: card}`. Of course that won't work because `render` is supposed to return a react element, not an object. So, it's wrong but not for the reasons you mentioned. And while you are right about all these things, you are still not solving the problem the OP asked about.

Comment: @Shubham Khatri, sorry for the silly mistake but I already try your suggestion. But it doesn't work for me. It still give me a warning.

Comment: @FelixKling I missed that in my answer. Thanks for reminding

Answer (score 0):

The only you missed is assign `that` to `this`

```
var myClass = React.createClass({
  myFun : function (value){  
      console.log(value);  
  },
  render: function () {
    var that = this; 
    var card = this.props.data.map(function (val,key) {
      return <p onClick={that.myFun.bind(null,val)}> Click Me</p>;
    });
    return <div>{card}</div>;
  }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

The best way to do this is to extract it into a sub-component and pass the params as props. This way you won't be creating a new function on every render, and will prevent unnecessary re-renders ([More info here `jsx-no-bind`)](https://github.com/yannickcr/eslint-plugin-react/blob/master/docs/rules/jsx-no-bind.md#protips):

```js
var Item = React.createClass({
  handleClick: function() {
    this.props.onItemClick(this.props.val);
  },
  render: function() {
    return (
      <p onClick={this.handleClick}>Click Me</p>
    );
  }
});

var MyClass = React.createClass({
  myFun: function (value){  
      console.log(value);  
  },
  render: function () {
    var that = this; 
    var card = this.props.data.map(function (val, key) {
      return (
        <Item onItemClick={that.myFun} val={val} />
      );
    });
    return (
      <div>{card}</div>
    );
  }
});

ReactDOM.render(
  <MyClass data={['a', 'b', 'c']} />,
  document.getElementById('test')
);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react-dom.min.js"></script>
<div id="test"></div>
```

Also you should look into using or learning es6, which will clean up your code considerably.

Comment: I can't do this because i am using so many bind for other function too. So I can't make classes for all that.