# react redux pass this.props to actions from component

Tags: reactjs, react-router, redux

In my component class I have `this.props` which contains `history` object which contains `transitionTo` function.

```
render() {
    console.log(this.props)

    return (
      <div>
        <button onClick={actions.myAction}>My button</button>
      </div>
```

Here my button is calling `myAction` which when completes wants to route to some other location. I want to access this `transitionTo` function in my `action` and performs something like `router.transitionTo("/page1")`

For this I should get `history` object which contains `transitionTo` function. So how can I pass `this.props.history` object to actions. When I do `onClick={actions.myAction(this.props.history)}` my button is not being rendered..

Any help

Comment: Be careful with the word "react", you could get sued.

Answer (score 1):

I do not agree with your approach, but find bellow the solution to your problem:

```
handleBtnClick() {
  actions.MyAction(this.props.history);
}

render() {
  return (
    <div>
       <button onClick={ this.handleBtnClick.bind(this) }>My button</button>
    </div>
  );
}
```

When your button is clicked the function `handleBtnClick()` is invoked and there you can call your action and pass any props you want.

`onClick` expects a function expression (something that evaluates to a function expression). You are not supposed to make complex calls in there such as `actions.myAction(this.props.history)`.

I would suggest you to consider using `react-router-redux` and handle url transitions using `routeActions` and custom redux middleware. I can expand this approach if you are interested.

**EDIT:**

If you use `react-router-redux` then you should take advantage of methods in `routeActions`. The method you need in this case is `push()`. So, if you want to transition to the **/user/account** url you just call `dispatch(routeActions.push('/user/account'))` and react-router-redux will handle the transition.

Eg:

```
import { routeActions } from 'react-router-redux';

// Action creator    
function mySuperAction(flag) {
  return (dispatch, getState) => {
    dispatch(routeActions->push('/user/account'));
  }
});
```

You need to have your store properly setup with react-router-redux in order for this to work.

Or from a component:

```
import { routeActions } from 'react-router-redux';
import { connect } from 'react-redux';
import React from 'react';

class MyComponent extends React.Component {
  handleClick() {
    this.props.dispatch(routeActions.push('/user/account'));
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
         <button onClick={ this.handleClick.bind(this) }>My button</button>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
export default connect()(MyComponent);
```

Comment: definitely I am looking for that.. I have implemented `react-redux-router` and in my action when I do `getState()` I am getting its giving me `router` objeect but it does not have `transitionTo` function so I cannot route this . this is why I want to implement this approach.. In my store I have implemented `reduxReactRouter` too. Please can you elaborate this

Comment: I think I am missing something with `store` .. when I print `store` in the console its giving me `dispatch, setState, history` and so on functions

Answer (score 1):

The answers above are correct, but fall appart when migrating to ["Stateless Components"](http://facebook.github.io/react/blog/2015/10/07/react-v0.14.html#stateless-functional-components) this quickly falls apart. My suggestion is using a higher-order function to take care of both the handling of preventing default click action and supplying the correct arguments. If you're already using ES2015 (through Babel for example), this could be this simple:

```
const preventDefault = (fn, ...args) => (e) => {
  e.preventDefault();
  fn(...args);
};
```

Then in your components call like so:

```
const Item = ({
  item,
  openItem
}) => (
  <div>
    <h1>{item.title}</h1>
    <a href="#" onClick={preventDefault(openItem, item)}>Open Item</a> // on click will call `openItem(item)`.
  </div>
)
```

Comment: Even though this method is not recommended on react github questions and on this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22639534/pass-props-to-parent-component-in-react-js but still when using redux and stateless components it becomes important that we are able to send component child back to some parent which is 4-5 links back in the chain.