# How to set a props from the child in ReactJs?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

Is there any way to set the props of the parent from child to parent?
At the moment I have taken the property but I want to manipulate it.
Exist something like`this.setProps` or I don't know in React in the same way we have `{this.setState}`?
Thank you.

Comment: You can pass a setter function to child and child can pass new value to it

Comment: you can check out here : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22639534/pass-props-to-parent-component-in-react-js

Comment: It worked that way,thank you @Rajesh

Comment: @XhinoAgalliu Ideally you component should not know the world outside it. All it should know is on a specific event, if you have a prop, you should call it.