# how to send data from one component to another component in react?

Tags: reactjs, react-router

could you please tell me how to send data from one component to another component in react ?
I do like this

```
 <Route path="/second/:testvalue" component={Second}/>
```

on Link function

```
 <Link to="/second/"{this.state.username}><button onClick={this.handleClick}>send data</button></Link>
```

But it not passing my data

here is my code
http://codepen.io/anon/pen/mOYgJV?editors=1011

Comment: This doesn't appear to be ReactNative code. Would you please remove the react-native tag.

Comment: You should read http://stackoverflow.com/q/22639534/2955679.

Answer (score 0):

React is build for Flux pattern. You emit events, than a dispatcher though PubSub pattern passes those event to subscribers, which are usually components.

Take a look at official description at https://facebook.github.io/flux/.

Answer (score 0):

Here you can use props to pass data between two components

```
<Second data={your data }/>
```

in First Component you can access the data using props by writing `this.props.data.`

in your example you can set the state of data on button click and you can pass the state value in `<Second data={this.state.data }/>`

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
<Link to={`/second/${this.state.username}`}><button onClick={this.handleClick}>send data</button></Link>
```