# pass props between unrelated components- react

Tags: reactjs

I have a **HeadingComponent** that shows page heading inside an h2 tag like so:

```
<div id="id1">
      <h2 className="class1">{headingText}</h2>
 </div>
```

This **HeadingComponent** is inside a parent div that has other components and divs embedded. **ComponentThatDecidesHeading1, ComponentThatDecidesHeading2, ComponentThatDecidesHeading3** are the components that will decide what should be the {headingText} i.e.

```
<div id="layoutContentArea">
              <HeadingComponent headingText={headingText}/>
               <div or some wrapper component>
                     <ComponentThatDecidesHeading1/>
                     OR
                     <ComponentThatDecidesHeading2/>
                     OR
                     <ComponentThatDecidesHeading3/>
                  </div>
             </div>
```

So, if **ComponentThatDecidesHeading1** is rendered, headingText= 'Heading 1', if **ComponentThatDecidesHeading2** is rendered, headingText = 'Heading 2' and so on.

Is there a way to put an "if" condition or something that checks which component is rendered and based on that display the corresponding headingText?
Or 
Pass headingText from, ,  and fetch that in .

I checked [ReactJS Two components communicating](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21285923/reactjs-two-components-communicating), [Pass props to parent component in React.js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22639534/pass-props-to-parent-component-in-react-js), but didn't get my answer.

Any ideas?

Comment: who chooses which heading to render? Is it done by the user?

Comment: Why not make a component - `ComponentThatDecidesHeading` and pass in the props as required to determine the component/heading?

Comment: @Dhiraj- the presence of components "ComponentThatDecidesHeading1", "ComponentThatDecidesHeading2" etc. decides the heading. As I mentioned, if the component that is currently rendered is "ComponentThatDecidesHeading1", then the heading will be "Heading 1" , so on and so forth. "HeadingComponent" is the component that shows that heading inside its "h2" tag.

Comment: @Nevin Madhukar K- I didn't fully understand from your answer, where exactly in the DOM structure will that "ComponentThatDecidesHeading" lie. If this component is not a direct sibling of "HeadingComponent", then how to pass props between these 2 components?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create a function that's called within your render() function to conditionally render the component you want while also setting your heading text. I'm assuming here that you have a "ComponentThatDecidesHeading" component that receives different props from somewhere else. If that's the case, something like this would work (**EDITED** to respond to your inquiry):

```js
// Elsewhere in your app:

const propsForMyHeadingComponents = [
{ 
   id: 1,
   headingText: 'HeadingText 1',
   data: [thing1, thing2...]
},
{ 
   id: 2,
   headingText: 'HeadingText 2',
   data: [otherThing1, otherThing2, ...]
},
etc...
];

// Meanwhile, in your parent component:

grabDataAndHeadingText(){
  let headingText;
  let component;

  // Assuming the info you need to load into your components is passed in 
  // from a parent or from a store like Redux:
  const { propsForMyHeadingComponents } = this.props;

  // From there, you can iterate through your array to select the data for the component you want:
  propsForMyHeadingComponents.forEach(thisHeader => {
    if(condition-to-determine-which-component-to-load === thisHeader.id){
      headingText = thisHeader.headingText;
      data = thisHeader.data;
  });
   
  return { data, headingText };
}

render(){

  const { data, headingText } = this.grabDataAndHeadingText();

  // Again, assuming "ComponentThatDecidesHeading" is the same component 
  // with changing props:

  return(
    <div id="layoutContentArea">
      <HeadingComponent headingText={ headingText }/>
        <div or some wrapper component>
            <ComponentThatDecidesHeading data={ data } />
        </div>
    <div>
  );
}
```

You could always get & set headingText and component variables to state, as well.

If you literally have 100 separate components that each have their own set of unique logic, etc... , you can store the component's name in your "propsForMyHeadingComponents" array. Otherwise, just load your component with the props you want to render it with as outlined above.

Comment: Thanks Nate. Yes, I am going to have a lot of components (may be 100) that decide heading. Could you share the other method as well please?

Comment: @abhi See above.

Comment: It worked. Like you said, all my "components that decided heading" were different from each other (had their own unique logic etc.). So, I used your approach with slight modification.

const compWithNextPage = [
 { 
    currentPage: 'abc',
    nextPage: 'xyz',
    headingText: 'headin1',
    bodyContent: <ComponentThatDecidesHeading1 props1={props1} props2={props2}/>
  },
  { 
     currentPage: 'def,
     nextPage: 'ghi',
     headingText: 'heading2',
     bodyContent: <ContentThatDecidesHeading2 props1={props1} props2={props2}/>
   }, 
]