# child component using onChange(), update parent component

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs

I have three components, one controller, and two childrens of this controller. 
For this problem we need a controller and one children (his name is : Input.js)

So, I expose the problem. In my `Input.js` I call the `onChange()` method and updated inside of this file the state and in my controller I passing a props for recover the the state in my children.

But I have an error `this.props.myName is not a function`

Please you can take a look of this code inside :

** Input.js **

```js
import React, { Component, Fragment } from "react";

class Input extends Component {

  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    console.log(props);
    this.state = {
      email: "",
      password: ""
    };

  _handleChange(pEvt) {
    if (pEvt.target.type === "email" && pEvt.target.value.length >= 6) {
      this.setState({
        email: pEvt.target.value
      });
    } else {
      this.setState({
        password: pEvt.target.value
      });
    }
  }
  
  render() {
    const { type, placeholder } = this.props;
    return (
      <Fragment>
        <div className="form__group">
          <input
            className="form__input"
            type={type}
            placeholder={placeholder}
            ref={input => (this.refInput = input)}
            onChange={pEvt => {
              this._handleChange(pEvt);
            }}
          />
        </div>
      </Fragment>
    );
  }
}

export default Input;
```

** SignInUp.js (Controller) **

```js
import React, { Component } from "react";
import Header from "./../Header/Header";
import Input from "./../Input/Input";
import Submit from "./../Input/Submit";
import "./_SignInUp.scss";

class sign extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      input: []
    };
  }

  _inputValue = email => {
    this.setState({
      input: [...this.state.input, email]
    });
  };

  render() {
    return (
      <div className="sign">
        <Header />
        <form className="form">
          <Input
            inputValue={this._inputValue}
            type="email"
            placeholder="Email"
          />
          <Input type="password" placeholder="Password" />
          <div className="form__submit">
            <Submit name="Sign in" to="/profile" />
            <Submit name="Sign Up" to="/" />
          </div>
        </form>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default sign;
```

Comment: I couldnt figure out from your code where are you using inputValue, It doesnt show up in the Input component. Maybe you missed some code?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Pass props to parent component in React.js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22639534/pass-props-to-parent-component-in-react-js)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- In your implmentation, the `Sign` class doesn't know the `value` of of `Input` classes.
- Input class can be implemented without state.
- The `setState` shouldn't use itself to update, you can use `prevState`, but it doesn't need in this case. https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#setstate
- `Fragement` doesn't do anything, so it doesn't need to be there, since it already has a `div` wrapper.

There is an example based on your code:

```
class Input extends Component {
  _handleChange = event => {
    this.props.onChang(event.target.value);
  }

  render() {
    const { type, placeholder, value } = this.props;
    return (
      <div className="form__group">
        <input
          className="form__input"
          type={type}
          placeholder={placeholder}
          onChange={this._handleChange}
          value={value}
        />
      </div>
    );
  }
}

class SighUp extends Component {
  state = {
    email: '',
    password: '',
  };

  render() {
    return (
        <form>
          <Input
            type="email"
            placeholder="Email"
            value={this.state.email}
            onChang={val => { this.setState({ email: val }); }}
          />
          <Input
            type="password"
            placeholder="Password"
            value={this.state.password}
            onChang={val => { this.setState({ password: val }); }}
          />
          <button onClick={e => { e.preventDefault(); console.log(this.state); }}>Console log</button>
        </form>
    );
  }
}
```

There is the codesandbox for this demo: https://codesandbox.io/s/k01mvwroq5

Does this demo help?

Comment: Thanks for your answer :) Enjoy !