# Property 'onload' does not exist on type <ImgHTMLAttributes>

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-tsx

There is my code to use image tag in typescript

```
<img
  className="mediaImg"
  src={imageUrl}
  onload={() => console.log('dffffffffffffffffffffffff')}
  style={{ ...theme.messages.mediaImg }}
/>
```

When I use `onload` attribute there I get the error

```
Property 'onload' does not exist on type 'DetailedHTMLProps<ImgHTMLAttributes<HTMLImageElement>, HTMLImageElement>'
```

Any help would be appreciated!!!
Thank you

Comment: i think its only a typo `onLoad` (with a upper L)

Comment: Then I get this `Type 'void' is not assignable to type '((event: SyntheticEvent<HTMLImageElement>) => void) | undefined'.`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to call `onLoad` instead `onload`.

```
<img
 className="mediaImg"
 src={imageUrl}
 onLoad={() => console.log('dffffffffffffffffffffffff')}
 style={{ ...theme.messages.mediaImg }}
/>
```

Comment: Then I get this `Type 'void' is not assignable to type '((event: SyntheticEvent<HTMLImageElement>) => void) | undefined'.`

Comment: am not getting any errors or warnings, may be its problem with your `style={{ ...theme.messages.mediaImg }}`

Comment: I was not returning anything in the onLoad function and I integrated eslint in my code.

Comment: Hi one more question how do I pass prop from one component to another in typescript?

Comment: google it, you will get many references. check here -> https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22639534/pass-props-to-parent-component-in-react-js