# React - Pass and Read Props to Inner Components

Tags: reactjs, react-router, react-props

I found my self working with a react template and route.
I am not able to pass props to inner component in order to change page title.

Route are defined as below in the template a I **added** "*title*" props for each routes in order to pass to inner components.

```
const loadable = loader =>
  Loadable({
    loader,
    delay: false,
    loading: () => null,
  })

const loadableRoutes = {
  '/registration': {
       component: loadable(() => import('sm-pages/RegistrationPage')),
       title : "Registration"
  },

  '/registrationSuccess': {
        component: loadable(() => import('sm-pages/RegistrationPage')),
        title : "Registration Success"
   },

  ...

  render() {
    return (
      <ConnectedSwitch>
        <Route exact path="/" component={HomePage} />
        {Object.keys(loadableRoutes).map(path => {
          const { exact, ...props } = loadableRoutes[path]
          props.exact = exact === void 0 || exact || false // set true as default
          return <Route key={path} path={path} {...props} />
        })}
        <Route
          render={() => (
            <Page>
              <NotFoundPage />
            </Page>
          )}
        />
      </ConnectedSwitch>
    )
  }
```

The template has differents inner components and at some point it render my component as below:

```
render() {
    const { getContentBuffer } = this.context
    const { pathName, content } = getContentBuffer()
    return isEmpty(content) ? (
      <div className="utils__loadingPage" />
    ) : (
      <div className="utils__content">
        <Breadcrumb name={pathName} />
        {content}
      </div>
    )
  }
```

I access to props (without success) in my component in this way:

```
 render() {  
    const props = this.props
    return (        
        <h1>{this.props.title}</h1>
    )
  }
```

How I have to change in order to access to title props?

Thanks in advance

Comment: What is `Loadable`? Is it able to pass props at all?

Answer (score 0):

This is a problem that is similar to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52537325/how-can-i-pass-props-from-a-parent-to-child-with-this-props-children). Props are passed to `Route` component instead of `component`.

Considering that `loadable` is able to pass props to imported component, it likely should be:

```
  let { exact = true, component: WrappedComponent, ...routeProps} = loadableRoutes[path]
  exact = !!exact; // set true as default
  const WrapperComponent = props => <WrappedComponent {...routeProps} {...props}/>;
  return <Route key={path} path={path} exact={exact} component={WrapperComponent} />
```

Comment: Thanks @estus, I will try soon

Answer (score 0):

In our project we created helper component, which transfer all props from `Route` to `Component`:

```
// @flow
import * as React from 'react';
import {Route} from 'react-router';
import PropTypes from 'prop-types';

type Props = { component: React.ComponentType<*> };

export default class RouteProps extends React.Component<Props> {
    static propTypes = {
        component: PropTypes.func.isRequired,
    };

    renderMergedProps = (component: React.ComponentType<*>, ...rest: Array<Object>) =>
        React.createElement(component, Object.assign({}, ...rest));

    render() {
        const {component, ...rest} = this.props;
        return (<Route {...rest} render={routeProps =>
            this.renderMergedProps(component, routeProps, rest)}/>);
    }
}
```

You can just simply use it as usual:

```
<RouteProps path="/" component={HomePage} {...propsForHomePage}/>
```

Answer (score 0):

> Try this ..
>   
>   https://github.com/MrCookiez/onemiracle/tree/routes-setup

```
import React from 'react';
import styled from 'styled-components';

const Title = ({ title }) => <h1>{title}</h1>;

const HeroTitle = styled(Title)`
    text-align: center;
`;

const Hero = (props) =>  {  
    return (
        <HeroTitle title={ props.title } />
    );
};

export default Hero;
```