# How to maintain state using react-router

Tags: reactjs, react-router, state

I have a react app with a main App.js file that holds my initial state. I then have some routes setup to navigate around my application.

In one of the routes I have a button which when pressed processes a set state. I know that this works as I've console logged the change in state. However, it then also calls:

```
window.location.href = '/';
```

This then routes us to our homepage. However, once the homepage renders the state reverts to its initial setup as detailed in App.js. I don't know why state is not being maintained once I'm rerouted to another part of the website. Given I'm using react-router does this mean I need to use redux to handle the app's state?

Comment: you should use the history API that gets imported with react-router: https://reacttraining.com/react-router/web/api/history

Comment: Whenever a component is initialized, the state of that component is initialized as well. Since you are navigating to a new component, your state will be reinitialized. If you're looking to maintain props at the parent level and make changes from the child, check out this post:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22639534/pass-props-to-parent-component-in-react-js?answertab=active#tab-top

I would also recommend checking out react-router docs for a better understanding of how to navigate and pass props to and from components:

https://reacttraining.com/react-router/

Answer (score 10, accepted):

This is happening because you are redirecting using window object rather than react router. You don't need to use redux. To use react router, you need to use its **history** method. And then use it as follows, inside a component:

```
this.props.history.push('/');
```

For example take the following react functional component:

```
const LoginButton = ({ history }) => (
  <button onClick={() => { history.push('/login'); }} >
    Log in
  </button>
);
```

**Explanation:** The above component, destructures history from props, and then use it to redirect to login page

Link to history api: https://reacttraining.com/react-router/web/api/history