# Passing a value stored in a function within a child component to a parent in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-props

Below is my code.

CHILD COMPONENT

```
  const onSave = () => {
    var val = value
    props.onSave();
  }

<div onClick={() => { onSave() }}>
            <CheckButton variant="contained" text-align='center' />
          </div>
```

PARENT COMPONENT

```
export const Card = (props) => {
    const onSave = (val) => { [I WANT TO ACCESS val within here] }
}


<TextInputContainer onSave={() => onSave()} />
```

Is there any way I can access that variable `val` inside the parent component? The code is truncated big-time. The actual code uses Redux.

Comment: Look where the value is coming from. If it is coming from a prop, lift it upwards to the global redux state or to parent.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Pass props to parent component in React.js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22639534/pass-props-to-parent-component-in-react-js)

Answer (score 0):

The `createRef` of react helps u to access the value of a react component:

Reference (https://pt-br.reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html)

```
constructor () {this.CheckButtonRef = createRef()}
onSave = () => {props.onSave(this.CheckButtonRef.current.value)}
<CheckButton ref = {this.CheckButtonRef}/>
```