# How to pass an Array from Child component to Parent component in react I know how to pass from parent t

Tags: reactjs

I am working on a React project in that I am trying to pass an array from the child component to the parent component. But I don't know how to pass it

This is Parent component

```
import React from 'react';
import Child from './Child/Child'

function App() {
  return(
    <div className='App'>
      <Child></Child>
    </div>
  )
}

export default App
```

This is Child component

`````
import React from 'react';

function Child() {
  const employees = ['Williams','Steve']
  return(
    <div className='Child'>
    </div>
  )
}

export default Child

````
`````

Answer (score 3):

You can make use of hooks here.

Initialize a useState hooks in the parent component,
then pass the set method as a prop to the child component.

Then in the child component you can assign new array value to the parent using the set method.

eg:

In parent:

```
    import React, {useState} from 'react';
    import Child from './Child/Child'

    function App() {
      const [arr, setArr] = useState([]);
      return(
        <div className='App'>
          <Child setArrFunc={setArr}></Child>
        </div>
      )
    }

export default App
```

In child component:

```
import React, {useEffect} from 'react';

function Child({setArrFunc}) {

  const employees = ['Williams','Steve']
  useEffect(()=> {
 setArrFunc(employees);
},[]);
  return(
    <div className='Child'>
    </div>
  )
}
export default Child;
```

//Or you can make use of onClick Function and make use of the setArrFunc inside clickHandle method

Comment: Keep in mind this method would make the component re-render every time the array changed.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to pass something to the parent component the easiest way is to create a callback in `Parent` component that you use in `Child` component.

[Pass props to parent component in React.js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22639534/pass-props-to-parent-component-in-react-js?rq=1)

Answer (score 0):

In the parent define a method to handle the array:

```
import React from 'react';
import Child from './Child/Child'

function App() {
  const doSomething = (inputArray: string[]) => {
    // Do something with your array of strings in here
  };

  return (
    <div className='App'>
      <Child doSomethingMethod={this.doSomething}></Child>
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

Then you can utilise it in the child:

```
import React from 'react';

function Child() {
  const employees = ['Williams','Steve'];
  const doingSomething = () => {
    // blah blah
    // this method is an example where it takes the employees array as a fixed
    // array predefined elsewhere (above)
    this.props.doSomethingMethod(employees);
  };

  const doSomethingElse = (inputArray: string[]) => {
    // this method takes arguments then pushes them into the method to pass
    // to the parent
    this.props.doSomethingMethod(inputArray);
  };

  return (
    <div className='Child'></div>
  );
}

export default Child
```