# Passing onClick from child to parent

Tags: reactjs, gatsby

I have component `foo.js` with the stack of cards with the 2 button (open and close modal) but in the same time i want to pass the event to the parent `bar.js`.

My motivation is to change the parent class when the event occured, in this case i want the outer wrapper to be `overflow hidden` when the open button get clicked and get back to normal for the close button.

```
// foo.js

import React from 'react'

class GridWithModal extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            lecturerList: this.props.lecturers,
            lectorIndex: null,
            isModalOpen: false
        };
        this.showModal = this.showModal.bind(this);
    }

    showModal(id) {
        this.setState({
            lectorIndex: id,
            isModalOpen: true
        });
    }
   
   render() {
     const { lecturerList, lectorIndex, Content } = this.state;
     
     return (
        <>
          {lecturerList.map((lector, index) => {
              return (
                 // my card stuff here...
                 <button
                     onClick={e => {
                          this.showModal(index); // this open the modal 
                     }}>
                      Open The Modal
                 </button>
              )
          })}

           
          <div className="modal">
             // modal stuff here
             <button
             onClick={e => this.setState({ dosenIndex: null })}> // this close the modal
             Close Modal
             </button>
          </div>
          
        </>
     )
   }

}

export default GridWithModal
```

```
// bar.js
import React from 'react'

const Layout = ({children}) => {
  
  return (
      <div className="bar"> // this is the element that i want to pass the event to add and remove class when the event occured
         <main> 
             {children} // foo.js somewhere inside this chilldren
        </main>
      </div>
  )

}

export default Layout
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Pass props to parent component in React.js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22639534/pass-props-to-parent-component-in-react-js)

Comment: it should. basically, you have to declare the hook in the parent, and then pass it down to the child to call it. if that doesn't suit your liking, you can use useReducer and useContext hooks

Comment: @FerranBuireu thanks for the refference, i read it but i'm still lost on how to put the `{props.handleThisClick}` in my both button cause they already have function in it

Answer (score 1):

Create the `show/hide` methods in parent component `bar.js` and pass these methods to child component.

Upon click action, just call these methods from child component & it should do the trick.

Answer (score 0):

Your `bar.js` should pass a prop to `foo.js` and then, in your `onClick` you should call the `prop` function passed back to `bar.js`.

Answering this:

> @FerranBuireu thanks for the reference, I read it but I'm still lost
> on how to put the `{props.handleThisClick}` in my both button cause they
> already have a function in it

In that case, in `foo.js` you should use a function that manages both functions. Changing this:

```
 <button onClick={e => this.showModal(index)}>
```

To this:

```
<button onClick={e => this.handleStuff(index)}>
```

Then, your `handleStuff` function should be:

```
handleStuff(id){
  showModal(id)

  props.handleModal(modalState) // change modalState for your value or state
}

showModal(id) {
    this.setState({
        lectorIndex: id,
        isModalOpen: true
    });
}
```

In `bar.js`, your function `handleModal` will be triggered when `handleStuff` is being executed inside the child component.

Comment: that is the problem that i tired to solve, how can i pass the prop because the bar.js is deep nested under `{children}`, By the way what exactly `props.handleModal(modalState)` where and how i should define it in this foo.js?  by now it throws me an error because it's not define

Comment: You can still achieve it, the idea still the same. `props.handleModal` is received via `props`, it's defined in `bar.js`, you don't need to define it in the children component.